# Why does roxygen interpret a documentation field as code?

Tags: r, roxygen2, r6

I'm building a package that contains a simple R6 class in a file.  The class definition begins as follows:

```
#' @import R6 RBGL bnlearn

#' An R6 for a generated scale-free network
SFNetwork <- R6Class("SFNetwork", list(
```

And then I get the following warnings and an error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  there is no package called ‘for’
2: In loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  there is no package called ‘scale-free’
3: In loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  there is no package called ‘An’
4: In loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  there is no package called ‘a’
5: In loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  there is no package called ‘generated’
6: In loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  there is no package called ‘network’
7: SFNetwork.Rd is missing name/title. Skipping 
Documentation completed

==> R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source NetRes

* installing to library ‘/home/boris/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’
* installing *source* package ‘NetRes’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘for’
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
```

I can't begin to imagine what's happening, except maybe some arcane roxygen formatting issue?

Comment: Can you try `importing` on three lines, instead of one?

Comment: That worked, though I now get a different error:
Error in Rd_info(db[[i]]) : 
  missing/empty \title field in '/home/boris/Projects/NetRes/man/NetGen.Rd'
Almost certainly unrelated

But why multiple lines?  I'm sure I've used single line imports before!

Comment: I can't give you a satisfactory answer to why it is the case, but I know that it throws me errors if I do not do it when I document my own packages. You also need to add a title to your function, otherwise it will not work as intended. Titles and descriptions are required. Please refer to https://r-pkgs.org/man.html

Comment: I added a line then deleted a line and it no longer works, still breaks with the same error

Comment: Add your full `roxygen2` notes, otherwise we are just shooting in the dark. But we are moving beyond the original question. I believe we are moving into "How to use roxygen2" as a general question now.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to import `packages` independently,

```
#' @import R6
#' @import RBGL
#' @import bnlearn
```

When importing `functions` from `packages`, you can do,

```
#' @importFrom methods setClass setGeneric setMethod setRefClass
```

Multiple package `imports` inline, as you have done, gets interpreted as `#' @importFrom` and thus your syntax is erroneous. Hence the error.

Comment: 1. after some editing, this fix no longer works.  Further, I've used multiple package imports in a previous package.

Comment: See my comment above :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is rather unbelievable but I found the cause: I was missing the @title tag in the first line of the document.  The messages were further fuzzied by errors due to a stale file in the man/ folder.  Removing those and adding the title field fixed the problem.  P.S. single-line import works fine.

Comment: Yeah - titles are a must as mentioned in the comments! :-) So `#' @import R6 RBGL bnlearn` works out of the box?

Comment: Yes; I have had a production package with that type of usage for a year.  Though it's probably a bad idea to import the whole environment in most cases :)